# Access Redux Variable in createStackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using a stacknavigator in my react native app and want to determine whether the header is shown or not depending on a variable in redux.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Screen1: {
            screen: FirstScreen,
            headerMode: variable.fromRedux ? "none" : "screen"
        }
        Screen2: {
            screen: SecondScreen
        }
    }
)
```

How do you pass redux variables to the createStackNavigator? Otherwise can anyone suggest another way to do this?

Comment: are you disabling/enabling the header in the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly import the store and access the state like;

```
import store from './store/index' // depends to where and how you exported the store, its just my example

const state = store.getState();
```

Then you can use the state in the stack navigator however you like

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Screen1: {
            screen: FirstScreen,
            headerMode: state.headerShown ? "none" : "screen"
        }
        Screen2: {
            screen: SecondScreen
        }
    }
)
```

Just an example how you can use the state :)

Hope it helps

Comment: I still have one problem. When the redux variable is changed, the status of the header doesn't update unless the app is manually reloaded

Comment: createStackNavigator can be static,initialized on creation, I don't know

Comment: In react-navigaiton 4.x I used something like this in the options,

 defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
   return {
    drawerLockMode: navigation.state.index === 0 ? 'locked-closed' : 'unlocked',
   };
  },

But now I even I don't know what that does ://